# Efficient way on sorting priority queue of objects by specified value

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I want the priority queue auto to sort its elements in ascending way by objects' value.
"Entry" is one of my custom class.
Currently I'm doing it in this way:

```
static Comparator<Entry> comparator = new MindistComparator();
static PriorityQueue<Entry> listH = new PriorityQueue<Entry>(10, comparator);

public class MindistComparator implements Comparator<Rtree.Entry> {

@Override
public int compare(Rtree.Entry o1, Rtree.Entry o2) {
    if(o1.getMindist() < o2.getMindist()){
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(o1.getMindist() > o2.getMindist()){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Custom class: entry

```
public static class Entry{
    private Node node;
    private Double mindist;
    
    public Entry(Node node, Double mindist){
        this.node = node;
        this.setMindist(mindist);
    }


    public void setMindist(Double mindist) {
        this.mindist = mindist;
    }

    public Double getMindist() {
        return mindist;
    }
}
```

I measure the execution time by running:

```
listH.add(new Entry(n,mindist));
```

several times (let's say 1000.).

I can get the correct output through above code. But this process still takes longer time than I expected. I'm looking for a more efficient way to sort the priority queue.

Comment: Please post the implementation of `getMindist` as well.

Comment: Your comparator could be reduced to `Comparator.comparingInt(Rtree.Entry::getMindist)`, but I doubt that the performance problem you're facing, if any, comes from the comparator implementation (unless getMindist() tries finding the meaning of life every time it's called). What is your code, what does it do, and how do you measure that it's slow?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo Hi I have added the implementation of "Entry" class, getMindist is a getter to get one of the entry's attributes which I want to sort by.

Comment: @ShidiYang ok thanks! I don't see anything obviously slow with the sorting. Please see JB Nizet's comment too. How do you measure that it's slow?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, it should be `Comparator.comparing(Rtree.Entry::getMindist)`, which would be marginally faster than yours (and much clearer and more concise, too). But again: what is slow, and how do you measure it?

Comment: @JBNizet Hi! Thanks for help! Your way save the execution time about 5-10 times

Comment: @AndréLaszlo I subtract the System.nanoTime() before and after execute this part of the code to get its execution time.

Comment: @JBNizet I subtract the System.nanoTime() before and after execute this part of the code to get its execution time.

Comment: Which part of the code? Executed how many times? Benchmarking in Java is hard. The JIT will optimize your code if it's called often enough. But again, which code? Post it.

Comment: @JBNizet This is part of the code to implement an "efficient" algorithm, but the total time for this algorithm is much longer than the brute-force way. And  I found this sorting part cost the majority of the time.

Comment: OK. I'm done. I've asked you to post the code 3 times and you won't do it, so it's impossible to help more.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for misunderstanding. I measure the execution time by running: listH.add(new Entry(n,mindist)); several times, so that each time a new element added in, the priority queue will auto sort it in ascending. Pls refer to my new edit.

Comment: @dididaisy Please add the full code you used for benchmarking (you might not be measuring what you think). Could you also add the measured time for running your benchmark with 0 nodes added, 1 node added, 10, 100, 1k, 10k and so on until it takes a minute or so to run.

Comment: Proclaiming "process still takes longer time than I expected" is too vague to be a meaningful problem statement.